# Seleniun Webdriver difference between Firefox/Chrome and Safari

Tags: selenium-webdriver, firefox, safari

I am traversing a web page using Selenium Webdriver with java application. It works fine with Firefox and Chrome Webdriver, but not with Safari. My differences are with the getData method following a findElement on xPath. It looks like with firefox and chrome I get the displayable data and with safari I get CSS data? intermixed. Sample output with firefox and safari:

```
**Safari**

First Last FollowGolf Club2.6HANDICAP  INDEX ®LOW H.I.2.2ScoresScoreDateC.R./SlopePCC   infoDifferentialCourse
    .t446e7af4-1355-44fc-8835-7c11933d39e5 {
        color: #fff;
        background: #222;
        border: 1px solid transparent;
    }
    .
    .
    .
    
    
  **Firefox**
  
  First Last
Follow

GOLF CLUB
2.6
HANDICAP
INDEX ®
LOW H.I.
2.2
Scores
SCORE
DATE
C.R./SLOPE
PCC   
info
DIFFERENTIAL
COURSE
```

I am pretty incompetent when it comes to CSS, not even sure that's what's following .t44... What am I doing wrong in safari to get all that extra data?

```
public String getData(String xpath) {
    
    WebElement data;
    data = findElement("xpath", xpath);                                         // Data div[4/5]
    if (data == null) {
        return null;
    }
    return data.getText();                                                      // Data
}
```

Comment: Update the question with your code trials