# Selenium Webdriver Firefox vs Safari

Tags: java, selenium, safari, webdriver

I posted:

[Seleniun Webdriver difference between Firefox/Chrome and Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70441290/seleniun-webdriver-difference-between-firefox-chrome-and-safari) a month or so earlier.

I was asked to post tests. I finally got around to setting up a better test case. [This](https://pastebin.com/nfSZ8XaX) is my test webpage.

My test code:

```
@Test
@Order (2)
void getDataFromFirefox() {
    
        Optional<Path> browserPath = WebDriverManager.firefoxdriver().
                getBrowserPath();
        WebDriver driver = null;
        if (browserPath.isPresent()) {
            FirefoxOptions firefoxOptions = new FirefoxOptions();
            firefoxOptions.setHeadless(true);
            WebDriverManager.firefoxdriver().setup();
            driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxOptions);
        }
        
        driver.get("file:///.../ghinTest-1.html/");
        System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"main-content\"]")).getText());
        driver.close();
}

@Test
@Order (3)
void getDataFromSafari() {
    
        Optional<Path> browserPath = WebDriverManager.safaridriver().
                getBrowserPath();
        WebDriver driver = null;
        if (browserPath.isPresent()) {
            SafariOptions safariOptions = new SafariOptions();
            WebDriverManager.safaridriver().setup();
            driver = new SafariDriver(safariOptions);
        }
        
        driver.get("file:///.../ghinTest-1.html/");
        System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"main-content\"]")).getText());
        driver.close();
}
```

I get significantly different results when using Firefox vs Safari:

```
***** Firefox *****

Michael Erickson
Follow

NCGA TEST CLUB
!
6.6
HANDICAP
INDEX ®
LOW H.I.
2.9
Scores
9-Hole Score waiting to be combined
Score
Date
C.R./Slope
PCC   info
Differential
Recent Scores
56 H
01/2022
34.0/120
PCC   
info-
20.7
Revision Scores
93 C
12/2021
69.3/124
PCC   
info-
21.6
* 78 H
11/2021
72.4/139
PCC   
info-
4.6
* 83 C
10/2021
71.1/128
PCC   
info-
10.5
91 C
10/2021
70.5/131
PCC   
info-
17.7
* 73 E
10/2021
73.8/135
PCC   
info-
-1.7
!
93 C
10/2021
69.6/126
PCC   
info-
20.0
!
84 C
10/2021
65.1/108
PCC   
info-
18.8
!
100 C
09/2021
70.7/128
PCC   
info-
24.9
!
85 C
09/2021
70.7/128
PCC   
info-
11.6
!
90 H
09/2021
72.4/139
PCC   
info-
13.3
!
87 C
09/2021
69.8/129
PCC   
info-
14.1
!
92 C
09/2021
69.8/129
PCC   
info-
18.4
!
* 84 C
09/2021
69.8/129
PCC   
info-
11.4
!
88 C
09/2021
69.8/129
PCC   
info-
14.9
!
* 79 H
09/2021
70.1/123
PCC   
info-
7.2
!
* 85 H
09/2021
72.4/139
PCC   
info-
9.2
!
93 C
09/2021
68.1/118
PCC   
info-
22.8
!
94 H
09/2021
70.7/133
PCC   
info-
18.8
!
* 85 C
09/2021
71.6/128
PCC   
info-
10.8
!
* 79 H
08/2021
71.3/133
PCC   
info-
5.5
!
Score Type: H - Home, A - Away, C - Competition, N - Combined 9-Hole Rounds, P - Penalty, E - Exceptional


***** Safari *****

Michael Erickson FollowNCGA Test Club!
    .t819258eb-c684-4596-816b-d1c31a7a7c10 {
        color: #fff;
        background: #222;
        border: 1px solid transparent;
    }

    .t819258eb-c684-4596-816b-d1c31a7a7c10.place-top {
        margin-top: -10px;
    }
    .t819258eb-c684-4596-816b-d1c31a7a7c10.place-top::before {
        border-top: 8px solid transparent;
    }
    .t819258eb-c684-4596-816b-d1c31a7a7c10.place-top::after {
        border-left: 8px solid transparent;
        border-right: 8px solid transparent;
        bottom: -6px;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -8px;
        border-top-color: #222;
        border-top-style: solid;
        border-top-width: 6px;
    }

    .t819258eb-c684-4596-816b-d1c31a7a7c10.place-bottom {
        margin-top: 10px;
    }
    .t819258eb-c684-4596-816b-d1c31a7a7c10.place-bottom::before {
        border-bottom: 8px solid transparent;
    }
    .t819258eb-c684-4596-816b-d1c31a7a7c10.place-bottom::after {
        border-left: 8px solid transparent;
        border-right: 8px solid transparent;
        top: -6px;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -8px;
        border-bottom-color: #222;
        border-bottom-style: solid;
        border-bottom-width: 6px;
    }

    .t819258eb-c684-4596-816b-d1c31a7a7c10.place-left {
        margin-left: -10px;
    }
    .t819258eb-c684-4596-816b-d1c31a7a7c10.place-left::before {
        border-left: 8px solid transparent;
    }
    .t819258eb-c684-4596-816b-d1c31a7a7c10.place-left::after {
        border-top: 5px solid transparent;
        border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
        right: -6px;
        top: 50%;
        margin-top: -4px;
        border-left-color: #222;
        border-left-style: solid;
        border-left-width: 6px;
    }

    .t819258eb-c684-4596-816b-d1c31a7a7c10.place-right {
        margin-left: 10px;
    }
    .t819258eb-c684-4596-816b-d1c31a7a7c10.place-right::before {
        border-right: 8px solid transparent;
    }
    .t819258eb-c684-4596-816b-d1c31a7a7c10.place-right::after {
        border-top: 5px solid transparent;
        border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
        left: -6px;
        top: 50%;
        margin-top: -4px;
        border-right-color: #222;
        border-right-style: solid;
        border-right-width: 6px;
    }
  6.6HANDICAP  INDEX ®LOW H.I.2.9Scores9-Hole Score waiting to be combinedScoreDateC.R./SlopePCC   infoDifferential
    .t355f1439-aec2-49f8-b07d-321cb48fbbf4 {
        color: #fff;
        background: #222;
        border: 1px solid transparent;
    }

    .t355f1439-aec2-49f8-b07d-321cb48fbbf4.place-top {
        margin-top: -10px;
    }
    .t355f1439-aec2-49f8-b07d-321cb48fbbf4.place-top::before {
        border-top: 8px solid transparent;
    }
    .t355f1439-aec2-49f8-b07d-321cb48fbbf4.place-top::after {
        border-left: 8px solid transparent;
        border-right: 8px solid transparent;
        bottom: -6px;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -8px;
        border-top-color: #222;
        border-top-style: solid;
        border-top-width: 6px;
    }

    .t355f1439-aec2-49f8-b07d-321cb48fbbf4.place-bottom {
        margin-top: 10px;
    }
    .t355f1439-aec2-49f8-b07d-321cb48fbbf4.place-bottom::before {
        border-bottom: 8px solid transparent;
    }
    .t355f1439-aec2-49f8-b07d-321cb48fbbf4.place-bottom::after {
        border-left: 8px solid transparent;
        border-right: 8px solid transparent;
        top: -6px;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -8px;
        border-bottom-color: #222;
        border-bottom-style: solid;
        border-bottom-width: 6px;
    }

    .t355f1439-aec2-49f8-b07d-321cb48fbbf4.place-left {
        margin-left: -10px;
    }
    .t355f1439-aec2-49f8-b07d-321cb48fbbf4.place-left::before {
        border-left: 8px solid transparent;
    }
    .t355f1439-aec2-49f8-b07d-321cb48fbbf4.place-left::after {
        border-top: 5px solid transparent;
        border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
        right: -6px;
        top: 50%;
        margin-top: -4px;
        border-left-color: #222;
        border-left-style: solid;
        border-left-width: 6px;
    }

    .t355f1439-aec2-49f8-b07d-321cb48fbbf4.place-right {
        margin-left: 10px;
    }
    .t355f1439-aec2-49f8-b07d-321cb48fbbf4.place-right::before {
        border-right: 8px solid transparent;
    }
    .t355f1439-aec2-49f8-b07d-321cb48fbbf4.place-right::after {
        border-top: 5px solid transparent;
        border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
        left: -6px;
        top: 50%;
        margin-top: -4px;
        border-right-color: #222;
        border-right-style: solid;
        border-right-width: 6px;
    }
      Recent Scores56 H01/202234.0/120PCC   info-20.7Revision Scores93 C12/202169.3/124PCC   info-21.6* 78 H11/202172.4/139PCC   info-4.6* 83 C10/202171.1/128PCC   info-10.591 C10/202170.5/131PCC   info-17.7* 73 E10/202173.8/135PCC   info--1.7!93 C10/202169.6/126PCC   info-20.0!84 C10/202165.1/108PCC   info-18.8!100 C09/202170.7/128PCC   info-24.9!85 C09/202170.7/128PCC   info-11.6!90 H09/202172.4/139PCC   info-13.3!87 C09/202169.8/129PCC   info-14.1!92 C09/202169.8/129PCC   info-18.4!* 84 C09/202169.8/129PCC   info-11.4!88 C09/202169.8/129PCC   info-14.9!* 79 H09/202170.1/123PCC   info-7.2!* 85 H09/202172.4/139PCC   info-9.2!93 C09/202168.1/118PCC   info-22.8!94 H09/202170.7/133PCC   info-18.8!* 85 C09/202171.6/128PCC   info-10.8!* 79 H08/202171.3/133PCC   info-5.5!Score Type: H - Home, A - Away, C - Competition, N - Combined 9-Hole Rounds, P - Penalty, E - Exceptional
```

My expected result is what I get with Firefox (and Chrome). What am I doing wrong with Safari?

EDIT: Changed test webpage link to my pastebin since ancillary HTML files are not needed, and I can get rid of dropbox link.

Comment: Can you summarize the differences for a better view?

Comment: @undetectedSelenium I show the two above, but firefox shows the raw data and safari has a bunch of control fields interspersed.